# Vuex: Erasing store state back to an empty array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a Vuex store state called `scannedList` and the initial state is `[]`:

```
state: {
  scannedList: []
}
```

I have a mutation that pushes id's to the array.  I tried to clear all the state back to an empty array with:

```
store.commit('addToScannedList', [])
```

but the id's still remain within the array. What is the proper way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pushing an empty array onto an array won't clear it.  You can make a new mutation:

```js
resetScannedList(state) {
  state.scannedList = [];
}
```

Or you could make a condition in your existing mutation for clearing it if you don't pass a payload:

```js
addToScannedList(state, item) {
  if(item !== undefined) {
    state.scannedList.push(item);
  } else {
    state.scannedList = [];
  } 
}
```

Which you'd trigger with `store.commit('addToScannedList')` with no payload